# Enabling UIBarButtonItem in toolbar

Tags: objective-c

I have two UIBarButtons in DetailView. Buttons are placed on toolbar at the bottom of DetailView. I want to disable prev button when its first DetailView. How can i do that. i tried to use these both:
myController.prev.enabled = NO;
and
[myController.prev setEnabled:NO;
but both are not working.

and i have a back button on the top of detail view. i want it to work like that whenever i press that backbutton it should go to the main table view. but it always go to last detail page.

thanx for help in advance.